# not going through the django view through ajax post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am doing the login throgh ajax. jquery function is working fine but its not going to the ajax url. So django view is not getting executed.

Ajax.html

```
$(function()
                {
                localStorage['domain'] = "http://122.172.64.142";
                var domain = localStorage['domain'];

                $('#fac1').on('click', function () {
                        var username = $("#username").val();
                        var password = $("#pwd").val();
                        data = {
                            name: username,
                            password: password
                            };

                        alert(domain);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: domain + "/login/login_android_here/",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: data,
                            success: function (response) {
                                                alert("success");
                                                window.location = 'file:///android_asset/www/posts.html';
                                                    },
                                        error: function () {
                                            alert('some error in login');
                                        }
                            });
                                return false;
                            });
                    });
```

My django views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def login_android(request):
    print "i am in view"
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "you are in method"
        username = request.POST['name']
        password = request.POST['password']        
        login_api(request,username,password)
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        messages.success(request, 'You Loged In Successfully')
        response = json.dumps(username)
        return HttpResponse(response, mimetype="application/json")
```

When i click on login button i am getting alert but its not getting entered to view. Url is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I would first recommend using Chrome with the developer tools console open. 
You could change you alerts for `console.log()`.

When your trying `window.location = 'file:///android_asset/www/posts.html';`
You are trying to access a local resource. If I post that in my Chrome developer tools I get back
`Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/posts.html`

If you would use `window.location.replace("a url to your view");` this will work like a HTTP redirect.
for more information [redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

and you should be able to see your view.

Answer (score 0):

I was made a silly mistake. I provided a wrong domain address on this page. Now it worked.

```
localStorage['domain'] = "http://122.172.64.142";
```

This address was wrong. Thats why it was not able to enter in to the view.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot dataType ajax param

```
$.ajax({
    url: domain + "/login/login_android_here/",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    dataType : 'json', //dataType param IS MISSING
    success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
                window.location = 'file:///android_asset/www/posts.html';
                    },
        error: function () {
            alert('some error in login');
        }
});
```

Comment: Still not working,,,,, i think dataType is not matter for this perticuler ajax.

Comment: Try to change mimetype return to return HttpResponse(response, mimetype='application/javascript')